# JavaScript (function(){...}( )) and (function(){...} ) ( )

Tags: javascript

I've inherited a project with some Java Script. I know nothing about js. There are some auto-build steps involved, the result of which is an anonymous function. The version is version control is different from the version I build, even though the environments were supposed to be the same.

One version is, void parameter list inside the evaluation brackets:

```
(function(){...}( ))
```

The other version is, void parameter list outside the evaluation brackets:

```
(function(){...} ) ( )
```

Are these two forms technically the same? Is one form technically an error? Is either form actually an error?  Or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, both are equivalent and valid.

Note that for the first option, when the outer parentheses are excluded, that will result in a SyntaxError

```js
function(){...}() // error
(function(){...}()) // no error
(function(){...})() // no error
```

Comment: I didn't find the previous question, but now that I have, I still like your answer. It says exactly the same thing as the accepted answer in that question, but your's shorter, clearer, and easier to understand. Appropriate for a person who knows no js.